# AVEVA Wonderware Failed to deploy Platform, The platform cannot be deployed while certificates on the GR node and Platform Node are not matching

Tags: deployment, ide, wonderware

While deploy the platform i am facing following error.
Error: Failed to deploy <Platform_Name> : The platform cannot be deployed while certificates on the GR node and Platform Node are not matching. Check logger for more details.

SMC Log: The platform failed to deploy because the target node, <Platform_Name>, is not connected to the same System Management Server as the Galaxy Repository on <GRPlatform_Name>. Use the Configurator on the target node, <Platform_Name>, and connect it to the same System Management Server that <GRPlatform_Name> is connected to, reboot the target node, <Platform_Name>, then deploy the platform again.

Answer (score 1):

Reboot the Platform, redeploy again and able to deploy completed successfully.